# To perform a database replication with XAMPP MySql, do the Master and Slave need to have the same version?

Tags: mysql, xampp, replication

I have 2 servers with different versions of XAMPP, do they need to be the same version in order to replication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this has nothing to do with XAMPP versions, but MySQL versions. If so, no, you do not need to run same MySQL versions to use replication. However, it is highly recommended you do.

From MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-compatibility.html):

> **17.4.2 Replication Compatibility
> Between MySQL Versions**
>
> MySQL supports replication from one release series to the next higher release series. For example, you can replicate from a master running MySQL 5.6 to a slave running MySQL 5.7, from a master running MySQL 5.7 to a slave running MySQL 8.0, and so on. However, you might encounter difficulties when replicating from an older master to a newer slave if the master uses statements or relies on behavior no longer supported in the version of MySQL used on the slave. For example, foreign key names longer than 64 characters are no longer supported from MySQL 8.0.

I would suggest that you check the versions of the MySQL instances and upgrade them to the same version, if needed.